# Wrap a js function with a fixed this arg

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, event-handling, scope

If I use `node.addEventListener('click',Wyg.Editor.nodeClickedEvent);` then when `node` is clicked, `nodeClickedEvent` has `this`===`node`. Since `nodeClickedEvent` is a static function in a class, I want `this` to === `Wyg.Editor`, so I wrote a helper function to simplify it.

Helper Function:

```js
function fixThisFunc(object,functionName){
    const fixedFunc = function(){
        object[functionName].apply(object,arguments);
    };
    return fixedFunc;
}
```

How it's used:

```js
let node = document.getElementById('myFavoriteNode');
node.addEventListener('click', fixThisFunc(Wyg.Editor,'nodeClickedEvent'));
```

How it looked before:

> ```
> node.addEventListener('click',
>     function(event){
>         Wyg.Editor.nodeClickedEvent(event);
>     }
> );
> ```

The Wyg.Editor class is like:

```js
Wyg.Editor = class {

    static nodeClickedEvent(event){
        const clickedNode = event.target;
        console.log(this); //successfully outputs the Wyg.Editor object/class
        this.getEditableNode(clickedNode);
    }
//there are more functions, of course
};
```

I'm looking for a review of the Helper Function `fixThisFunc`

Are there any particular problems I should be worried about? is there a better way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Do you mean to use this for this particular scenario or as an API reusable across use cases?

Comment: isn't `bind` enough?\

Comment: @Semi-Friends, yes. Yes it is! Didn't know about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is there a better way to achieve this functionality?

You can use [`Function.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to create a function with the `this` context bound to `Wyg.Editor`:

```
const node = document.getElementById('myFavoriteNode');
node.addEventListener('click', Wyg.Editor.nodeClickedEvent.bind(Wyg.Editor));
```

See this demonstrated in the snippet below.

Notice that `const` was used instead of `let` - unless there is a reason to re-assign `node`, use `const`. This will help avoid [accidental re-assignment and other bugs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/278653/244085).

```js
const Wyg = {};
Wyg.Editor = class {

    static nodeClickedEvent(event){
        const clickedNode = event.target;
        console.log('nodeClickedEvent() - this: ', this); 
        
    }
};
const node = document.getElementById('myFavoriteNode');
node.addEventListener('click', Wyg.Editor.nodeClickedEvent.bind(Wyg.Editor));
```

```html
<button id="myFavoriteNode">click this favorite node</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

### Accessing statics via `this`

Defining the object reference outside the object just to gain access via a miss used accessor (`this`) is a hack and not how to use static objects to handle events.

#### Binding objects to a function

First what you did could have been a little less complicated

You had something like

```
class Editor {
    static nodeClick(event){
        this.editable(event.target);  // miss used 'this' to reference 'Editor'
    }
    static editable() {} 
}


function fixThis(object,functionName){
    const fixedFunc = function(){
        object[functionName].apply(object, arguments);
    };
    return fixedFunc;
}
node.addEventListener('click', fixThis(Editor,'nodeClick'));
```

Could have written the binding using `Function.call`

```
const  thisFunc = (obj, func) => (...args) => func.call(obj, ...args);
node.addEventListener('click', fixThis(Editor, Editor.nodeClick));
```

or using `Function.bind` as one line

```
node.addEventListener('click', Editor.nodeClick.bind(Editor));
```

### Access static via name

Static functions should access properties via the defined name. This makes it clear that you are accessing the static properties and conforms with static property accessed from within an instance of the object.

Your objects static access via name should look like

```
class Editor {
    static nodeClick(event){
        Editor.editable(event.target);  // correct reference to 'Editor'
    }
    static editable() {}
}
```

Then you don't need to bind `Editor` to `Editor.nodeClick` to maintain the correct reference. Just pass the static function as is, to the event

```
node.addeventListener("click", Editor.nodeClick);
```

Comment: I'll be using `bind`. I find that produces a much more predictable result, and I like it. Hacky or not. I don't want to hard code class names, because that makes my code more dependent upon my naming practices. Using `this` means I can refactor & rename things and still get the same result.

Answer (score 2):

> is there a better way to achieve this functionality?

You might use [a wrapping function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#In_an_inline_event_handler):

```
let node = document.getElementById('myFavoriteNode');
node.addEventListener('click', event => Wyg.Editor.nodeClickedEvent(event));

// or, using regular function expression
node.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  return Wyg.Editor.nodeClickedEvent(event);
});
```

Using a wrapper function lets you [keep the original context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method) of your `nodeClickedEvent` method the way you expect. You can use either arrow or regular function expression, because you don't care at all about the `this` value `addEventListener` provides to the callback.

Comment: The `event => ...` is far more concise than what I originally had, and I do kind of like it. But I'm gonna roll with `bind`. Fits how I like to code, because I'd rather use `this` wherever I can than use a hard-coded class name.